# Pivot over multiple tables with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I want to create a pivot with average values over multiple tables. Here is an example that I want to create: Inputs are `df1` and `df2`, `res` is the result I want to calculate from `df1` and `df2`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"2000": ["A", "A", "B"],
                   "2001": ["A", "B", "B"],
                   "2002": ["B", "B", "B"]},
                   index =['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"2000": [0.5, 0.7, 0.1],
                   "2001": [0.6, 0.6, 0.3],
                   "2002": [0.7, 0.4, 0.2]},
                   index =['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'])

display(df1)
display(df2)

res = pd.DataFrame({"2000": [0.6, 0.1],
                   "2001": [0.6, 0.45], 
                   "2002": [np.nan, 0.43]},
                   index =['A', 'B'])

display(res)
```

Both dataframes have years in columns. Each row is an item. The items change state over time. The state is defined in `df1`. They also have values each year, defined in `df2`. I want to calculate the average value by year for each group of states `A`, `B`.

I did not achieve to calculate `res`, any suggestions?

Comment: Are the indices and  columns of the two dataframes always the same ?

Comment: @Psidom yes they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you should merge both DataFrames in one, at first. For example you can use this code convert dataframe from wide to long and then merge both of them by the index (year, item), and finally reset the index to be used as a column in the pivot:

```py
df_full = pd.concat([df1.unstack(), df2.unstack()], axis=1).reset_index()
```

[image: long dataframe]

Then, if you want, you can rename columns to build a clear pivot:

```py
df_full = df_full.rename(columns={'level_0': 'year', 'level_1': 'item', 0: 'DF1', 1:'DF2'})
```

[image: new names for columns]

And finally build a pivot table.

```py
res_out = pd.pivot_table(data=df_full, index='DF1', columns='year', values='DF2', aggfunc='mean')
```

[image]

It's not a one line solution, but it works.

```py
df_full = pd.concat([df1.unstack(), df2.unstack()], axis=1).reset_index()
df_full = df_full.rename(columns={'level_0': 'year', 'level_1': 'item', 0: 'DF1', 1:'DF2'})
res_out = pd.pivot_table(data=df_full, index='DF1', columns='year', values='DF2', aggfunc='mean')
display(res_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code using stack, join and unstack should work:

```
df1_long = df1.stack().to_frame().rename({0:'category'}, axis=1)
df2_long = df2.stack().to_frame().rename({0:'values'}, axis=1)
joined_data = df1_long.join(df2_long).reset_index().rename({'level_0':'item','level_1':'year'}, axis=1)
res = joined_data.groupby(['category', 'year']).mean().unstack()

display(res)
```